# Spark Twitter Streaming

Tags: scala, twitter, apache-spark

I am new to Spark and Scala. I wrote a program for fetching a hashtag or tweet on Twitter, using Spark Streaming. My code is this:

```
  val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("SparkTwitterHelloWorldExample");
    val jssc = new StreamingContext(conf, new Duration(1000));
    System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.consumerKey", consumerKey);
    System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.consumerSecret", consumerSecret);
    System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.accessToken", accessToken);
    System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.accessTokenSecret", accessTokenSecret);

  val twitterStream=TwitterUtils.createStream(jssc, None, Array("#Spark")) 

    // Without filter: Output text of all tweets
  val statuses = twitterStream.map{ status => status.getText() }
  val hashTags = statuses.filter(word => word.startsWith("#Spark"))
  val tagCounts = hashTags.window(Seconds(100), Seconds(10)).countByValue()
  hashTags.count().print();
  tagCounts.count().print();
  jssc.start();
```

This code always print 0, and I do not know why? Can you please help me if anybody knows, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think that right now, this code will just look for tweets with a status starting with #Spark. Apart from that, I would suggest lowercasing the text, so you can find #Spark, #spark, #SPARK, etc. Can you try this?

```
val hashTags = statuses.filter(word => word.toLowerCase.contains("#Spark"))
```

The other option is to first get all of the hashtags in the status, then continue from the list of hashtags. You can find examples of that in the spark examples:

```
https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/streaming/TwitterPopularTags.scala
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Now, when I am printing the hashTags, I am getting the time for the job which is Time: 1450611281000 ms.. Can you please tell me how to get the statuses?

Comment: And for this example you gave me, I am again getting 0.. I do not know what is the problem